# How to verify ihe Interpolation inequality for the weighted Bessel potential spaces?

Tags: interpolation, holder-inequality, potential-theory

I am trying to prove the following:
Let $w$ be an admissible weight, $p_1,p_2\in[1,\infty)$, $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathbb{R}$, $\theta\in(0,1)$ and
\begin{equation}
 \alpha=\theta\,\alpha_1+(1-\theta)\,\alpha_2,
~~~
 \frac{1}{p} = \frac{\theta}{p_1} + \frac{1-\theta}{p_2}.
\end{equation}
There exists $C\in(0,\infty)$ such that for all $f\in L^{{\alpha}_1}_{p_1}(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{{1/p}_1})\cap L^{{\alpha}_2}_{p_2}(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{{1/p}_2})$ it holds
\begin{equation}\label{1}
 \|f\|_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p})} \leq C\,\|f\|^\theta_{L^{\alpha_1}_{p_1}(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p_1})}\, \|f\|^{1-\theta}_{L^{\alpha_2}_{p_2}(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p_2})}\,,
\end{equation}
where $\|f\|_{L_p^\alpha(\mathbb{R}^d,w)}$ is the weighted Bessel potential of order $\alpha$ with the following Definition:
The weighted Bessel potential space $L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w)$ is the Banach space with the norm
\begin{equation}
 \|f\|_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w)} := \|(1-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}f\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w)}\,
\end{equation}
such that the norms $\|\cdot\|_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w)}$ and $\|w\cdot\|_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d)}$ are equivalent. Moreover, we define for $s\in \mathbb{R}$, the Bessel potential of order $s$ to be the
(sequentially) continuous bijective linear operator $\mathbb{J}: S\to S$ by
\begin{equation}
(1-\Delta)^{s/2}:=\mathbb{J}^{s} u = F^{-1}(1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}F u\,.
\end{equation}
Using the above one has
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{J}^{s+t} = \mathbb{J}^{s}\mathbb{J}^{t}\,.
\end{equation}
The above interpolation inequality is known for Besov spaces and Triebel-Lizorkin spaces using section 1.6.7. on page 44 of H. Triebel, Theory of Function Spaces II, (1992).But, I would like to have it for the the weighted bessel potential space $L^{\alpha}_{p}(\mathbb{R}^d,w)$.  The following is my idea:
\begin{equation}
 \|f\|^p_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p})} = \|w^{1/p}(1-\Delta)^{{\alpha}/2} f\|^p_{L_p(\mathbb{R}^d)} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |w(x)^{1/p} (1-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} f(x)|^p dx
\end{equation}
Using $p = \theta p + (1-\theta) p$, $ \alpha=\theta\,\alpha_1+(1-\theta)\,\alpha_2$ yields
\begin{equation}
 \|f\|^p_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p})} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |w(x) (1-\Delta)^{\frac{{\alpha}_1}{2} \theta p} f^{\theta p}(x)  (1-\Delta)^{\frac{{\alpha}_2}{2} (1-\theta)p}  f^{(1-\theta)p}(x) |dx\,.
 \end{equation}
By assumption $1 = \frac{\theta p}{p_1} + \frac{1-\theta p}{p_2}$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
 \|f\|^p_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p})} \leq C \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|w(x)^{\frac{\theta p}{p_1}} (1-\Delta)^{\frac{{\alpha}_1}{2} \theta p} f^{\theta p}(x)|\,dx    \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} | w(x)^{\frac{1-\theta}{p_2}p}(1-\Delta)^{\frac{{\alpha}_2}{2} (1-\theta)p} f^{(1-\theta)p}(x)| dx,
\end{equation}
where $C$ only depends on the weight $w(x)$ (In particular, I used the fact that for every $b\in\mathbb{N}^d$ there exists $C\in(0,\infty)$ such that $|\partial^b w (x)|\leq C\, w(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$). Now, by the Holder inequality one has
\begin{equation}
 \|f\|^p_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p})} \leq C \Big[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|w(x)(1-\Delta)^{\frac{{\alpha}_1}{2} p_1} f^{p_1}(x)|\Big]^{\frac{\theta p}{p_1}}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} | w(x)(1-\Delta)^{\frac{{\alpha}_2}{2}p_2} f^{p_2}(x)|^{\frac{1-\theta}{p_2}p} dx
 \end{equation}
It holds,
\begin{equation}
 \|f\|_{L^\alpha_p(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p})} \leq C\,\|f\|^\theta_{L^{\alpha_1}_{p_1}(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p_1})}\, \|f\|^{1-\theta}_{L^{\alpha_2}_{p_2}(\mathbb{R}^d,w^{1/p_2})}\,.
\end{equation}
It seems ok as far as $\alpha$ is integer but for non-integer values I think there might be a problem. Any idea is welcome and thank you in advance.